# ZFS create brace expansion like mkdir -p

Tags: bash, shell, freebsd, zfs

As described on zfs manual, `-p` has the same effect as mkdir -p. I know that `{...}` is a brace expansion. So, is there a way to archive similar under zfs create command or I missing something?

`zfs create -p -o recordsize=1M tank/media/{movies,music,series}`

I got this error.:

```
too many arguments
usage:
        create [-pu] [-o property=value] ... <filesystem>
        create [-ps] [-b blocksize] [-o property=value] ... -V <size> <volume>

For the property list, run: zfs set|get

For the delegated permission list, run: zfs allow|unallow
```

I am using bash/zfs on freenas (fresh install).

Comment: The shell will expand `tank/media/{movies,music,series}` to `tank/media/movies tank/media/music tank/media/series` which is obviously too many parameters for `zfs create`. You could try wrapping the command inside a shell `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

As [@richard-smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith) pointed out in a comment, brace expansion expands your command to this:

```
zfs create -p -o recordsize=1M tank/media/movies tank/media/music tank/media/series
```

Which is incorrect. To create multiple filesystems, you must use a loop:

```
for path in tank/media/{movies,music,series}; do zfs create -p -o recordsize=1M "$path"; done
```